# Creating Lookup column using rest which can take multiple values

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

To create a lookup column..

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://test/_api/Lists/getbytitle('abc')/fields/addfield",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ 'parameters': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldCreationInformation' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 7,'Title': 'Platform', 'LookupListId': '30dfdfd3-013A-4D31-8E84-s542434332432','LookupFieldName': 'Platform_x0020_Name' } }",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",

  },
  success: function(d) {
        alert("added");
                },
  error:  function(e) {
                alert("error"); 
        }
});
```

this creates a lookup column but I need this column to take multiple values.

[image]

allow multiple value checkbox should be checked.

Comment: Can you try `Mult:"TRUE"` in request body? Meaning use data: `"{ 'parameters': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldCreationInformation' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 7,'Title': 'Platform', 'LookupListId': '309AC643-013A-4D31-8E84-3382248FF202','LookupFieldName': 'Platform_x0020_Name' , 'Mult': true} }"`

Comment: Error is coming `The property 'Mult' does not exist on type 'SP.FieldCreationInformation'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `'AllowMultipleValues': true`

**Edit**

To change lookup and enable allow multiple values You can refer same MSDN which Atish shared :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
    /fields('1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1')",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldLookup' }, 'AllowMultipleValues': true }",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: Nope .... It does not work!

Comment: Ohh Ok , it should I guess. Have you tried.

Comment: Yup..... error is **The property 'AllowMultipleValues' does not exist on type 'SP.FieldCreationInformation'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.**

Comment: You are right. That is for SP.FieldLookup

Answer (score 4):

You can create lookup column from `SchemaXml`. For multi value lookup column, `SchemaXml` looks like

```
var lookupShema = "<Field Type=\"LookupMulti\" DisplayName=\"MultipleLookup\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" List=\"{92a6545e-e509-430b-a6a6-16bdb7a81b33}\" ShowField=\"ID\" Mult=\"TRUE\" Sortable=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" RelationshipDeleteBehavior=\"None\" ID=\"{32e8961d-d69f-448e-bf9a-f2246185d389}\" SourceID=\"{233ae45e-f581-4420-b069-b7a74d368b13}\" StaticName=\"MultipleLookup\" Name=\"MultipleLookup\" ColName=\"int3\" RowOrdinal=\"0\" Version=\"1\" /> "
```

See *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx)* example for more details.

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
    /fields",
  type: "POST",
  data: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 20, 'Title':
    'Stakeholders', 'SchemaXml': '<Field Type=\"UserMulti\" Required=\"TRUE\"
    UserSelectionMode=\"PeopleAndGroups\" UserSelectionScope=\"0\" Mult=\"TRUE\" />' },
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')/fields('1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1')",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldLookup' }, 'AllowMultipleValues': true }",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```